# Constant Updating php Query

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, sql-update

i need to update a message box every second or so and i dont really have a clue what to do and i also do most coding differently to what i find online, heres my code

```
<?php
//first connect to the database
require_once('includes/connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `MetalM` WHERE `class` LIKE :msg";
$paragraph = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$paragraph->bindValue(':msg','Message',PDO::PARAM_STR);
$paragraph->execute();
?>
```

This is the code for my connection

```
<?php
try
{
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE', 'USER', 
'PASSWORD');
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
echo 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
exit;
}
?>
```

this is the code for where my messages are being loaded

```
<div id="mesgBox">
<?php
foreach ($paragraph as $key) {
echo '<div id="messages"><p>'.$key['Name'].': <br>'.$key['Message'].'</p></div>';


}            
?>
</div>
<div id="sndmsg">
<h1>Message:</h1>
<form action="insert.php" method="GET">
<input id="meassage" name="meassage" type="text" placeholder="Text Here">
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<br>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: How would i do that ??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this with Ajax.

You ll need to set Set up a timer that will retrieve every x seconds the new data

for example:

**Requirements: jQuery**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
setInterval(function(){
   $.post ('/get-update.php', function(data,success) 
   {
      if (success=='success')
         if (data.status=='ok')
             $('#messages').html(data.Messages);
   },'json');
},5000);
</script>
```

Now, you will have to change your php a little bit in order to make this work.

-- EDIT --

ok, let me refine..

You will need to include jquery lib in your head

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you will need to have a php file which does exactly what you need to do.... (bring the new messages)

as in:

```
<?php
// file name: get-update.php
// Just this code here.
require_once('includes/connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `MetalM` WHERE `class` LIKE :msg";
$paragraph = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$paragraph->bindValue(':msg','Message',PDO::PARAM_STR);
$paragraph->execute();


$TextBuffer ="";
$StringFormat = "<div id='messages'><p>%s : <br>%s</p></div>";
while ($row = $paragraph->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  $TextBuffer .= sprintf($StringFormat, $row['Name'],$row['Messagge']);

echo json_encode(array("status"=>"ok","Messages"=>$TextBuffer));

?>
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer but could you please explain more as i have no previous xp with this launguage and what i will need to change in my code or if ill need to make a new page on database. Thanks